# phpexcel can't get values from array

Tags: phpexcel

I can't realize to get values from my array into the cells at B2
Here the code:

```
    $row = 2;
    $column = 'B';
    $head=array('ONE','TWO','THREE'); 
    foreach ($steps as $step) {

            $etat = Etat::find_by_step($code, $year);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($head, null, $column . $row);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('233748');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('f7f8f9');
            $column++;
    }
```

Normally i must get:

[image]

But i get this:

[image]

I think he repeat only one colum.

Anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$steps`? and what is the relationship between `$steps` and `$head`?

Comment: From $steps i get the number how much time the array must repeat the three columns. This query i don't have put in my question. $head is my array. I have changed my question, i found some good ideas from your previous posts. Do you have an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of incrementing column just once for each step, why not increment it by the size of $head

You'll also want to set the styling for the range of cells you're writing, not simply for the first cell in your head block

```
$row = 2;
$column = 'B';
$head=array('ONE','TWO','THREE'); 
$stepSize = count($head);
foreach ($steps as $step) {

    $etat = Etat::find_by_step($code, $year);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($head, null, $column . $row);

    $rangeColumn = $column;
    for($i = 0; $i < $stepSize; $i++) 
        $rangeColumn++;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row . ':' . $rangeColumn . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row . ':' . $rangeColumn . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('233748');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row . ':' . $rangeColumn . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('f7f8f9');

    $column = $rangeColumn;
    $column++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, it works like a charm, thank you very much. I have changed only the for loop and replave value 1 because he counts 4 cells not three: for($i = 1; $i < $stepSize; $i++)   It is great thank you very much!!! best regards!